# AsyncTask returns null in OnPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to get text from a .txt located on a server to a string (feed_str)
My code:

```
public class getFeedData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params)
  {
    String feed_str = null;
    try
    {
        // Create a URL for the desired page
        URL url = new URL("http://www.this.is/a/server/file.txt");

        // Read all the text returned by the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        while ((feed_str = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("AsyncError: " + e);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("AsyncError: " + e);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("AsyncError: " + e);
    }
    return feed_str;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String feed_str)
  {
    super.onPostExecute(feed_str);
    System.out.println("onPostExecute " + feed_str);
  }
```

With this code the logcat should output something like: `"onPostExecute text from server"` but instead of that it outputs `"onPostExecute null"`

Any ideas how to fix?

Btw: The url has been checked with a browser and the text was displayed so the url isn't the problem.

Comment: Please post the full logcat.

Comment: post your full doInBackground code because probably u are not assigning value in `feed_str` after reading line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop doesn't exit until `feed_str == null`. So, the last value of it is null, which is what you return.

```
while ((feed_str = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
}
```

You need to keep a "total" String also, if that's what you want to return.

```
String entireFeed = "";
while ((feed_str = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    entireFeed += feedStr + "\n";
    // whatever else you're doing
}
...
return entireFeed;
```